# AVCaptureSession captureOutput callback drops frames and throws an OutOfBuffers Error

Tags: ios, avfoundation, opengl-es-2.0, avcapturesession

I am attempting to take an AVCaptureSession from the back camera and transfer it to a texture, mapped onto a quad.

View the [complete source here](https://github.com/gyrocade/VideoCaptureGL).

Regardless of any preset I use, the didDropSampleBuffer callback is reporting 'OutOfBuffers'. I have attempted to copy the sampleBuffer passed to didOutputSampleBuffer, but perhaps my implementation has an issue.

I have also tried to use a SERIAL_QUEUE, as I know captureSession's startRecording is a blocking function and it shouldn't be on the main queue.  However, using the main queue is the only way I've been able to see any frames.

Here is my AV setup:

```
- (void)setupAV
{
    _sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("cameraQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, self.context, NULL, &_videoTextureCache);
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create video cache.");
        return;
    }

    self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    if (!self.captureSession) {
        return;
    }

    [self.captureSession beginConfiguration];

    self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

    AVCaptureDevicePosition devicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;

    AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession *deviceDiscoverySession = [AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession discoverySessionWithDeviceTypes:@[AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera] mediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo position:devicePosition];

    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in deviceDiscoverySession.devices) {
        if (device.position == devicePosition) {
            self.captureDevice = device;
            if (self.captureDevice != nil) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    NSError *captureDeviceError = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:self.captureDevice error:&captureDeviceError];
    if (captureDeviceError) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't configure device input.");
        return;
    }

    if (![self.captureSession canAddInput:input]) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't add video input.");
        [self.captureSession commitConfiguration];
        return;
    }

    [self.captureSession addInput:input];

    self.videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    if (!self.videoOutput) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating video output.");
        [self.captureSession commitConfiguration];
        return;
    }

    self.videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
    NSDictionary *settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];
    self.videoOutput.videoSettings = settings;

    [self.videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    if ([self.captureSession canAddOutput:self.videoOutput]) {
        [self.captureSession addOutput:self.videoOutput];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't add video output.");
        [self.captureSession commitConfiguration];
        return;
    }

    if (self.captureSession.isRunning) {
        NSLog(@"Session is already running.");
        [self.captureSession commitConfiguration];
        return;
    }

    //            NSError *configLockError;
    //            int frameRate = 24;
    //            [self.captureDevice lockForConfiguration:&configLockError];
    //            self.captureDevice.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, frameRate);
    //            self.captureDevice.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, frameRate);
    //            [self.captureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
    //
    //            if (configLockError) {
    //                NSLog(@"Error locking for configuration. %@", configLockError);
    //            }

    [self.captureSession commitConfiguration];
}
```

And here is my captureOutput callback:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    //    if (_sampleBuffer) {
    //        CFRelease(_sampleBuffer);
    //        _sampleBuffer = nil;
    //    }
    //
    //    OSStatus status = CMSampleBufferCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, &_sampleBuffer);
    //    if (noErr != status) {
    //        _sampleBuffer = nil;
    //    }
    //
    //    if (!_sampleBuffer) {
    //        return;
    //    }

    CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    if (!_videoTextureCache) {
        NSLog(@"No video texture cache");
        return;
    }

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);

    _rgbaTexture = nil;
    // Periodic texture cache flush every frame
    CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush(_videoTextureCache, 0);

    // CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage will create GLES texture
    // optimally from CVImageBufferRef.
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                _videoTextureCache,
                                                                pixelBuffer,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                                GL_RGBA,
                                                                (GLsizei)width,
                                                                (GLsizei)height,
                                                                GL_BGRA,
                                                                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                                0,
                                                                &_rgbaTexture);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage %d", err);
    }

    if (_rgbaTexture) {
        glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(_rgbaTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_rgbaTexture));
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    }
}
```

For completeness, here are the ivar and property declarations:

```
@interface AVViewController () <AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate> {

    CVOpenGLESTextureRef _rgbaTexture;
    CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef _videoTextureCache;
    dispatch_queue_t _sessionQueue;
    GLuint _program;
    GLuint _vertexArray;
    GLuint _vertexBuffer;
    CMSampleBufferRef _sampleBuffer;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) EAGLContext *context;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureSession *captureSession;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoOutput;
@property (readwrite) GLint vertexAttrib;
@property (readwrite) GLint textureAttrib;
@property (readwrite) GLint videoFrameUniform;
```

I have searched and searched and cannot find a solution to this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.